# How to rank within category in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have a set of different suppliers who have paid more or less on a list of invoice lines than I expected leaving me with a positive or negative variance against what I expected.  I have been able to rank the variances at a total level using the formula below

```
SUMPRODUCT(--(ABS(L3)<ABS(L$3:L$3137)))+1
```

This provides me with the ranking based on distance from zero of each variance so an overpayment of 10K is ranked the same as an underpayment of 10K

Then using the following formula i have tried to rank the variances by line by supplier

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B$2:B$100=B2)*(C$2:C$100>C2))+1
```

However this ranks positive numbers higher than negative numbers when i want the same result as the previous formula but at supplier level.

Could anyone help?

Comment: Do you have a sheet layout that you can post? Maybe an image or something? And tell us "I would like this in column C based on the categories in column B, ranking column A" or something like that. People who answer would rather knock this out in one go than go back and forth.

Comment: why you are not using `=RANK()` function?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B$2:B$100=B2)*(ABS(C$2:C$100)>ABS(C2)))+1
```